# Populate errors for objects

Tags: java

I have a map of objects and errors associated with those objects.

I have to do the following:

1. populate the errors in the object
2. populate errors for valid objects based on the following:

   - check the indicator property in the object ( Y | N | other )
   - if all have Y and if there are invalid records - need to reject all

Scenario 1: if there are records with different indicators,  then get all the valid records if any ( i.e., no errors associated with them ) and set the error description to inconsistent indicator.

Scenario 2: if all the records have indicator as Y and if there are any invalid records then get all the valid records if any and set the error description to rejected because indicator is set to Y.

---

The following is a working code.  How can I improve this further? I feel like I am looping the list more times than required.

```
private List<SomeClazz> populateBeansWithErrors(final Map<SomeClazz, Errors<String>> errorsMap) throws FinancialsSystemRuntimeException {
        final List<SomeClazz> someObjs = new ArrayList<>();

        for ( final Entry<SomeClazz, Errors<String>> entry : errorsMap.entrySet() )
        {
            SomeClazz someObj = entry.getKey();
            final Errors<String> errors = entry.getValue();
            populateErrorColumns(someObj, errors);
            someObjs.add(someObj);
        }

        checkAndSetErrorColumnsForValidRecords(someObjs);

        return someObjs;
    }

    private void checkAndSetErrorColumnsForValidRecords(final List<SomeClazz> someObj) {

        //split list into sub-lists based on the indicator.
        final List<SomeClazz> beansWithIndicatorY = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<SomeClazz> beansWithIndicatorN = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<SomeClazz> beansWithIndicatorNotValid = new ArrayList<>();

        filterListPredicatesOnAllOrNoneIndicator(someObj, beansWithIndicatorY, beansWithIndicatorN, beansWithIndicatorNotValid);

        String errorDescription = IndicatorValidator.INCONSISTENT_INDICATOR;

        //if there are records with different  indicators
        //then get all the valid records if any
        //and set the error description to inconsistent indicator.
        final List<SomeClazz> validRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        if(beansWithIndicatorN.size() > 0) {

            boolean extractValidN = false;
            if(beansWithIndicatorY.size() > 0) {
                validRecords.addAll(getValidRecords(beansWithIndicatorY));
                extractValidN = true;
            } else if(beansWithIndicatorNotValid.size() > 0) {
                extractValidN = true;
            }
            if(extractValidN) {
                validRecords.addAll(getValidRecords(beansWithIndicatorN));
            }

        } else if(beansWithIndicatorY.size() > 0) {

            boolean extractValidY = false;
            if(beansWithIndicatorNotValid.size() > 0) {
                extractValidY = true;
            } else {
                //if all the records have  indicator as Y
                //and if there are any invalid records
                //then get all the valid records if any
                //and set the error description to rejected because indicator is set to Y.
                final List<SomeClazz> invalidYRecords = getInvalidRecords(beansWithIndicatorY);
                if(invalidYRecords.size() > 0) {
                    extractValidY = true;
                    errorDescription = IndicatorValidator.REJECTED_INDICATOR_IS_Y;
                }
            }

            if(extractValidY) {
                validRecords.addAll(getValidRecords(beansWithIndicatorY));
            }
        }

        populateErrorColumnsForValidRecords(errorDescription, validRecords);
    }

    private void filterListPredicatesOnAllOrNoneIndicator(
            @NotNull final List<SomeClazz> someObj,
            @NotNull final List<SomeClazz> beansWithIndicatorY,
            @NotNull final List<SomeClazz> beansWithIndicatorN,
            @NotNull final List<SomeClazz> beansWithIndicatorNotValid) {

        for(SomeClazz someObj : someObj) {
            if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(SomeClazz.getAllOrNoneIndicator(), INDICATOR_IS_Y)) {
                beansWithIndicatorY.add(someObj);
            } else if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(SomeClazz.getAllOrNoneIndicator(), INDICATOR_IS_N)) {
                beansWithIndicatorN.add(someObj);
            } else {
                beansWithIndicatorNotValid.add(someObj);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<SomeClazz> getInvalidRecords(final List<SomeClazz> someObj) {
        return select(someObj, having(on(SomeClazz.class).getStatus(), equalTo(CollateralTransactionReportStatus.REJECTED.name())));
    }

    private List<SomeClazz> getValidRecords(final List<SomeClazz> someObj) {
        return select(someObj, having(on(SomeClazz.class).getStatus(), isEmptyOrNullString()));
    }

    private void populateErrorColumnsForValidRecords(final String errorDescription, final List<SomeClazz> validRecords) {
        for(final SomeClazz validRecord : validRecords) {
            validRecord.getErrors().add(errorDescription);
        }
    }

    private void populateErrorColumns(final SomeClazz someObj, final Errors<String> errors) {
        if(errors.hasErrors()) {
            someObj.setErrors(errors.getErrorDescriptions());
            Logger.info("Validation errors exist in the file for row {}", someObj.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: How many records are we talking about here? more than 10, more than 100 more than 10,000 or more than 1,000,000 ?

Comment: number of records can be upto 10,000. Also, this can process multiple files at the same time in different threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a few generic notes:

1. I guess you're using SLF4J here:

   > ```
   > Logger.info("Validation errors exist in the file for row {}", someObj.toString());
   > ```

   The `toString()` call is unnecessary, SLF4J will call it for you (and it will call only if you have enabled info level logging).

   ```
   Logger.info("Validation errors exist in the file for row {}", someObj);
   ```
2. I wouldn't go with `size()` here:

   > ```
   > if(beansWithIndicatorN.size() > 0) {
   > ```

   `!isEmpty` would be a little bit easier to read and closer to English:

   > ```
   > if (!beansWithIndicatorN.isEmpty()) {
   > ```
3. For naming here:

   > ```
   > private List<SomeClazz> populateBeansWithErrors(final Map<SomeClazz, Errors<String>> errorsMap)
   >         throws FinancialsSystemRuntimeException {
   >     final List<SomeClazz> someObjs = new ArrayList<>();
   >     ...
   >     return someObjs;
   > }
   > ```

   I'd rename to `someObjs` to `result` to express its purpose.
4. The name of the following variables are too similar to each other:

   ```
   beansWithIndicatorY
   beansWithIndicatorN
   beansWithIndicatorNotValid
   ```

   I'd try to choose something which is easier to tell each other apart, like: `yesBeans`, `noBeans`, `invalidBeans`.
5. I supposed that the `someObj` parameter should be `someObjs`:

   > ```
   > private void filterListPredicatesOnAllOrNoneIndicator(
   >         @NotNull final List<SomeClazz> someObj,
   >         @NotNull final List<SomeClazz> beansWithIndicatorY,
   >         @NotNull final List<SomeClazz> beansWithIndicatorN,
   >         @NotNull final List<SomeClazz> beansWithIndicatorNotValid) {
   >
   >     for(SomeClazz someObj : someObj) {
   >         if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(SomeClazz.getAllOrNoneIndicator(), INDICATOR_IS_Y)) {
   >             beansWithIndicatorY.add(someObj);
   >         } else if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(SomeClazz.getAllOrNoneIndicator(), INDICATOR_IS_N)) {
   >             beansWithIndicatorN.add(someObj);
   >         } else {
   >             beansWithIndicatorNotValid.add(someObj);
   >         }
   >     }
   > }
   > ```

   Are you sure that the loop is correct here? The inner conditions don't depend on the iterated value, so if `SomeClazz.getAllOrNoneIndicator()` doesn't change on its subsequent calls, the following is the same:

   ```
    private void filterListPredicatesOnAllOrNoneIndicator(
           @NotNull final List<SomeClazz> someObjs,
           @NotNull final List<SomeClazz> beansWithIndicatorY, 
           @NotNull final List<SomeClazz> beansWithIndicatorN,
           @NotNull final List<SomeClazz> beansWithIndicatorNotValid) {

       if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(SomeClazz.getAllOrNoneIndicator(), INDICATOR_IS_Y)) {
           beansWithIndicatorY.addAll(someObjs);
       } else if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(SomeClazz.getAllOrNoneIndicator(), INDICATOR_IS_N)) {
           beansWithIndicatorN.addAll(someObjs);
       } else {
           beansWithIndicatorNotValid.addAll(someObjs);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: agree with all of them, but, I would like to mention a mistake that I made when refactoring my code to paste in stackoverflow. So, #5 is because of improper refactoring. But, thanks for your suggestion.